# How to delete Specialist Pool in Document AI Google cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I have created so many Specialist pools as a part of my research for human in the loop concept in Document AI.

Now I am unable to find how to delete the specialist pools which I have created

Please help.

Regards,
Nalini

Answer (score 0):

Document AI doesn't currently support the ability to delete Labeler Pools for Human in the Loop.